# Use Jackson to process Ember JSON API request

Tags: java, json, ember.js, jackson, servlet-3.0

I'm using Ember to build the client application and the backend is an Java Servlet, using [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) to process the calls.

The create customer call from ember looks like this :

```
{  
   "customer":{  
      "name":"4545",
      "email":"454545",
      "authenticator":"facebook"
   }
}
```

With the JSON data in this format I CANNOT use the simple solution from Jackson

```
mapper.readValue(jsonData, Customer.class);
```

As the customer fields are not in the first level of the JSON data. I had to process the JSON data to get the customer fields, and implemented like this :

```
JsonNode rootNode = mapper.readTree(jsonData);
Iterator iterator = rootNode.fields();
Entry first = (Entry) iterator.next();
ObjectNode node = (ObjectNode) first.getValue();
mapper.readValue(node.toString(), Customer.class);
```

But I'm looking for a better way to do it, or something out of the box from Jackson. any suggestions ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try ignoring the first level data to ignore the `customer` field and process inner data using the [`DeserializationConfig.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE`](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.9.4/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/map/DeserializationConfig.Feature.html#UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE) property (**This feature is included within the 1.9.0 and onward versions**):

> Feature to allow "unwrapping" root-level JSON value, to match setting of SerializationConfig.Feature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE used for serialization. Will verify that the root JSON value is a JSON Object, and that it has a single property with expected root name. If not, a JsonMappingException is thrown; otherwise value of the wrapped property will be deserialized as if it was the root value.

This will include just one additional instruction to configure your mapper:

```java
mapper.configure(SerializationConfig.Feature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);
try
{
  Customer customer = mapper.readValue(jsonData, Customer.class);
}
catch (IOException ioe)
{
  //...
}
```

You may need also to add the root element name of your model class if not already added so Jackson can match it with the root level name in the JSON feed at deserialization time:

```java
@JsonRootName("customer")
public class Customer {
//...
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! Used also mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);

Comment: Absolutely, your serialization style should be in conjuction with the deserialization one, but since you dind't tackle that in the OP I didn't want to hijack the main issue. :)